# Python action client does not connect properly

Tags: action, ros-kinetic, actionlib, action-server, action-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a problem with an action client not connecting to the server. I stuck as close to [the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Action%20Client%20(Python)) as possible. I tested that the server works by using `rosrun actionlib axclient.py /robot_skills/pick` as proposed [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/194379/actionlib-problems-when-try-to-connect-client-server/).

Still, the code below would get stuck on "Waiting for result".

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import rospy
import actionlib

import geometry_msgs.msg
import robot_skills.msg

class ExampleClass(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.pick_client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('/robot_skills/pick', robot_skills.msg.pickAction)

  def do_pick_action(self, robot_name):
    goal = robot_skills.msg.pickGoal()
    rospy.loginfo("Sending empty pick action goal")
    rospy.loginfo(goal)

    self.pick_client.send_goal(goal)
    rospy.loginfo("Waiting for result")
    self.pick_client.wait_for_result()
    rospy.loginfo("Getting result")
    return self.pick_client.get_result()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  rospy.init_node('assembly_example')
  tutorial = ExampleClass()
  tutorial.do_pick_action("a_bot")
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300405/python-action-client-does-not-connect-properly/) by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2180 on 2018-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The connection to the server wasn't ready, so the goal does not arrive at the server, and the code waits for a result that would never come. Don't waste hours like me, wait for your action servers after starting up your clients or before calling.

```
class ExampleClass(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.pick_client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('/o2as_skills/pick', o2as_skills.msg.pickAction)
    self.pick_client.wait_for_server()
```

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2018-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-13**:\

> wait for your action servers after starting up your clients or before calling

As the tutorial actually does :)

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-08-13**:
I know :( But I've googled stupider things before, maybe someone someday can save an hour.